# on click event on JQuery chosen plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m using JQuery chosen, and I read the API and I see that only this events are publish

```
   change: Chosen triggers the standard DOM
   chosen:ready Triggered after Chosen has been fully instantiated.
   chosen:maxselected   Triggered if max_selected_options is set and that total is broken.
   chosen:showing_dropdown  Triggered when Chosen’s dropdown is opened.
   chosen:hiding_dropdown   Triggered when Chosen’s dropdown is closed.
   chosen:no_results    Triggered when a search returns no matching results.
```

But in my case what I want is an event when I click in one of the elements of my dropdown, even if the value has not change.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you need to roll your own. Eg.: `$(document").on('click', 'li.item', function() { // do something with $(this) // }`

Comment: Yes, but if I do that I cannot get the option value that I need, since the li.item is created on render time

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can! Check the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qjjcx2bj/3/

By getting the index of the selected list item, you can retrieve the value of the selected item.

```
var ind = $(this).attr('data-option-array-index');
$("#select1").children('option:eq('+ind+')').val();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks I was expecting that the library had an event for this.Shame of them!